# Access Sparse Matrix from .mat File in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to work with the bcspwr01.mat file from https://sparse.tamu.edu/. When I try to load this file into MATLAB it loads as a 1X1 struct format. How can I extract the data from this struct format into the square matrix format so that I can perform matrix operations on the data.

Comment: How did you load the `.mat` file? Using `load(filename)` or `S = load(filename)`? If the latter, as described [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html), the contents of the file are loaded into a struct array and can be accessed via its fields.

Comment: I tried loading in both the formats and tried to access it using fields but could not figure out how to access it properly.

Comment: Could you try to access the data via `S = load(filename); A = S.Problem.A;`?

Comment: I tried doing this. It says reference to non-existence field 'A'.

Comment: Okay, that indicates that the `Problem` field is there at least. What do you get when looking at `S.Problem`?

Comment: struct with fields: a: 12.7000, b:NaN, c:999 and Problem is not there but it is old so I have to use S.old

Comment: Did you manage to access the desired data now? If not: Which `.mat` file did you use so I can try again?

Comment: Ah, I just noticed your OP contains the filename of the `.mat` file that you used. I admit I don't have access to MATLAB, but I succeeded loading the file in [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) with `S = load("bcspwr01.mat"); A = S.Problem.A;` as mentioned in one of my previous comments. If this is not working in MATLAB, I'm afraid I am not able to help any further.

Comment: One last guess: It might be that your version of MATLAB is *very* old (pre 1992) and does not [support sparse matrices](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/mat-file-versions.html)...

Comment: I upgraded my version of MATLAB and this did work for me. Thank you fir your help

Comment: Cool. You're welcome!